# Add ID tags to HTML tags using Python (BeautifulSoup?)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML file that contains certain tags, and I need to add ID numbers to each tag in the format `id="rule_1"`, `id="rule_1.1"`, `id="rule_1.2"`, `id="rule_1.2.1"`, etc. For example, current HTML is:

```
<div style="styles">
    <p class="classname">TEXT</p>
    <p class="classname">TEXT</p>
    <ul style="styles">
        <li>
            <p class="classname">TEXT</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="classname">TEXT</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need that HTML to look like this:

```
<div style="styles" id="rule_1">
    <p class="classname" id="rule_1.1">TEXT</p>
    <p class="classname" id="rule_1.2">TEXT</p>
    <ul style="styles" id="rule_1.3">
        <li id="rule_1.3.1">
            <p class="classname" id="rule_1.3.1.1">TEXT</p>
        </li>
        <li id="rule_1.3.2">
            <p class="classname" id="rule_1.3.2.1">TEXT</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can write these in manually, but I was hoping to use an existing HTML parser library.  Is it possible to do with BeautifulSoup, or another module?

I tried something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as html_parser

with open('outputs/HTML/{}.html'.format(deal), 'r') as read_file:
    html_source = read_file.read()

soup = html_parser(html_source, 'html.parser')
html_tags = soup.find_all(['div', 'p', 'span', 'ul', 'li'])

for each_tag in html_tags:
    each_tag.attrs['id'] = html_tags.index(each_tag)

with open('outputs/HTML/{}-id.html'.format(deal), 'w') as save_file:
    save_file.write(str(soup))
```

But this just adds `id="1"`, `id="2"`, and so on.  How can I have it staggered like `1`, `1.1`, `1.1.1`, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out:

```
curr_tags = {}

for each_tag in html_tags:
    if html_tags.index(each_tag) == 0:
        each_tag.attrs['id'] = 'rule_1'
    else:
        parent_id = each_tag.parent.attrs['id']
        if parent_id in curr_tags.keys():
            curr_tags[parent_id] += 1
        else:
            curr_tags[parent_id] = 1
        each_tag.attrs['id'] = parent_id + '.{0}'.format(curr_tags[parent_id])
```